# Angular form validation in four step registration pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a  4 page registration module in AngularJS. I want to submit the details only at the end. The submit button will be enabled only after the user filled the mandatory fields in all four tabs. Also user can save the data in the middle of registration, there we don't need any mandatory field validation

I am using for different controllers and templates for 4 tabs as it needs large number of data as input.

How we can identify that the user filled the required fields in four different controllers.

I am using

> module.value()

for holding the user data as global. By this way i can share the user details between different controllers. But i cannot validate the form as it is in four different  controllers/tabs

```
serviceApp.value('UserData',{});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
<form name="formName" ng-controller="TheCtrl" ...>
```

Then there will be a variable named `formName` in the scope of `TheCtrl`. Its type will be [FormController](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3aform.FormController). Note the form object has `$valid` and `$invalid` properties.

Put a required field under this form like:

```
<form name="formName" ng-controller="TheCtrl" ...>
    <input name="myInput" ng-required ... />
```

The form object will have `$invalid=true` if `myInput` is not filled-in.

---

The above describes the principle of the solution. You should have 4 forms and 4 corresponding controllers. Each controller, if defined as above, knows the validity of its corresponding form. A shared service (or even a field in your `model.value()`) will track the state of the validity of each form, e.g.:

```
app.controller("Form1Ctrl", function($scope, sharedService) {
    $scope.$watch("form1Name.$valid", function(newval) {
        sharedService.validity.form1 = newval;
    });
    ...
});
```

And the final submit button is enabled only when all forms are valid:

```
<button ng-disabled="   sharedService.validity.form1 == false
                     || sharedService.validity.form2 == false
                     || sharedService.validity.form3 == false
                     || sharedService.validity.form4 == false">
```